# Find duplicate files with different extensions using python

Tags: python, duplicates

**SOLUTION** see EDIT at bottom of this comment.

**PROBLEM:** I have a directory with a heap of images, named something like below:

- image001.nef
- image002.nef
- image003.nef
- **image003 - 20170609.jpg**
- image004.nef
- image005.nef
- image006 - 20170609.nef
- image007.nef
- **image007 - 20170609.jpg**
- **image008.jpg**
- image008 - 20170609.nef

I want to find all images that are a duplicate base name (like imageXXX) AND the extension is JPG

So from my above list, there are only three items that match the criteria to delete (i have **bold** those items).

I have 2,500 images so a pythonic way is desirable to me manually going through.

I am having a hard time finding an example script to use, all the ones I have found are checking the HASH or something, which I don't believe is useful as the images are indeed similar, but not identical.

Cheers

EDIT:
thanks to dawg I was able to get the output I desire... here is the final code that worked for me:

```
import os

directory = r'C:\temp'
out_directory = r'C:\temp\temp_usa_photos'
fns = os.listdir(directory)


ref_nef = {fn[0:15] for fn in fns if fn.upper().endswith('.NEF')}

print ref_nef

out_list = filter(lambda e: e[0:15] in ref_nef, [fn for fn in fns if fn.upper().endswith('.JPG')])

print out_list

for f in out_list:
    input_file = os.path.join(directory, f)
    output_file = os.path.join(out_directory, f)
    os.rename(input_file, output_file)
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You have to delete them only based on the filename? I don't exactly understand what prevents you from looping over all images, extracting base names, writing them to a dict/list and then removing all further duplicates encountered.

Comment: @moritzg i have just added code to original comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> fns
['image001.nef', 'image002.nef', 'image003.nef', 'image003 - 20170609.jpg', 'image004.nef', 'image005.nef', 'image006 - 20170609.nef', 'image007.nef', 'image007 - 20170609.jpg', 'image008.jpg', 'image008 - 20170609.nef']
```

(I can use that list as a proxy for a listing of file names. Just use a [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) or listdir for files...)

If your file names are all of the form `imageXXX` you can first use that to create a set of the file names first 8 letters of the `.nef` files:

```
>>> ref_nef={fn[0:8] for fn in fns if fn.upper().endswith('.NEF')}
>>> ref_nef
set(['image008', 'image005', 'image004', 'image007', 'image006', 'image001', 'image003', 'image002'])
```

Then use that to filter the `.jpg` files to delete:

```
>>> filter(lambda e: e[0:8] in ref_nef, [fn for fn in fns if fn.upper().endswith('.JPG')])
['image003 - 20170609.jpg', 'image007 - 20170609.jpg', 'image008.jpg']
```

Comment: I am wondering if there is a very simple solution to my new issue. Your solution fixed 99% of my  problem, but I just found out there are some rogue NEF files. If you see [this screenshot](http://i1355.photobucket.com/albums/q718/some_evil/2017-06-12%2020_44_20-temp_zpslkhxvmnt.jpg) you can see some duplicate NEF files are present, I am wondering if there is a way to rid my folder of all the NEWER nef files. In this case the top one needs to go, it will have a longer name AND be newer. Can you help with this one? Thanks heaps for your assistance!

Comment: If this does 99%, then use this. After, you can use a dup finding approach where you actually read the file and compare. A md5 hash is useful for this. Good luck. Ask a new question if you get stuck